# How can I make my image inside my scrollview/grid fit to the screen width with it's normal size?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working with a scrollview/grid! Inside my grid I have an image, button and a label.

In this page I gather my image from my database which means that the image is different depending on what category you clicked beforehand. This means that the images are not always the same height/width.

Some look good (they fill the full screen with their normal height) but some does not fill the screen at all. If I do a `AspectFill` some of the pictures gets chopped which I do not want either. I also tried `Fill` but that stretches the picture.

This is what I am working with:

```
    <ScrollView HorizontalOptions = "FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions = "FillAndExpand" >
    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions = "FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions = "FillAndExpand">

    <Grid>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>

        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor = "Red" HorizontalOptions = "FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions = "FillAndExpand">

            <Image  x:Name="theimage" Aspect = "AspectFit"  HorizontalOptions = "FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions = "FillAndExpand" />

            <Button Clicked="clickFunc" TextColor="White" Grid.Row="1" HeightRequest="80" WidthRequest="120" BorderRadius="40" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Start" />

        <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Padding="10,20,10,0">

            <Label TextColor = "#474747" x:Name="title" Text="" HorizontalOptions="Start" FontFamily="Helvetica Neue" FontAttributes="Bold" />

        </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </Grid> 
    </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

I tried to do this to fix the issue:

```
theimage.WidthRequest = App.ScreenWidth;
```

And I get the ScreenWidth from the AppDelegete but `theimage`does not change it's width at all. If I try to add a number manually like this in xaml:

```
WidthRequest = "500"
```

The image does not change either so I am a bit out of ideas when it comes to the image.

So how can I adjust my code so that my image always gets layed out fully to the screens width while it keeps it's normal size?

Comment: first of all your grid row height is auto  and second thing you can fix the height width with RowDefinition and ColumnDefinition both. for i.e. set both values to 50 and let me know if you face the issue.

Comment: Ok, let me see. I am new to work with grids so therefor I am not 100 % sure

Comment: Should I chage the row height from Auto to `*`? I added a `<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>`also, should I in my image add `Grid.Row="0"` ?

Comment: Did u get this fixed am facing same isses

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes you have to assign Grid.Row and Grid.Column as well to locate the exact location of your grid.
I have changed your code something like this: (values I have changed are for showcase only)

```
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>

    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor = "Red" HorizontalOptions = "FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions = "FillAndExpand">

        <Image Grid.Row="1"  x:Name="theimage" Aspect = "AspectFit"  HorizontalOptions = "FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions = "FillAndExpand" />

        <Button Clicked="clickFunc" TextColor="White" Grid.Row="1" HeightRequest="80" WidthRequest="120" BorderRadius="40" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Start" />

    <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Padding="10,20,10,0">

        <Label TextColor = "#474747" x:Name="title" Text="" HorizontalOptions="Start" FontFamily="Helvetica Neue" FontAttributes="Bold" />

    </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</Grid>
```

refer ,XAML docs how you can work with grid.

http://www.dailyfreecode.com/code/grid-layout-xaml-212.aspx
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/grid-in-wpf/

**Note**: for every row you have to provide Row-definition and same applies for the Column-definition as well.

Comment: I use your code but the image still does not adjust to the screen width

Comment: Some images do, but some don't

Comment: I added: `<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition x:Name = "width"/>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions> `As well and put `width.Width = App.ScreenWidth;` in the code. But still no change

Comment: have you added columndefinition for all the columns??